# What is this called - rear wheel edition?

Tags: ford, brakes, wheels, part-identification

A few weeks ago I heard a horrible sound when driving my 2000 Ford Ranger (V6, 4.0L, front disc rear drum) into work and when I parked my truck, I touched the left rear wheel and found that it was scaldingly hot. Eventually I managed to get it up on some jack stands (it has a lift kit so this was a bit problematic) and it looks to me like one of the springs on the left rear brake shoe snapped, presumably causing the rear brake shoe to fully engage while I was on the highway. In any case, this has really mangled up the left rear wheel... hub or whatever, and I'd like to replace it. Problem is I have no idea what the part is called, and searching "rear wheel hub assembly" gets me the wrong part. I can't seem to find an OEM parts "exploded diagram" showing the parts in the rear wheels, which would help immensely.

I'd really like to fix my truck ASAP, so maybe you guys could help me out. I have a picture here:

[image: Truck rear wheel]

What is the part labeled "What is this called" called? That part has some mangled parts. There's also a sleeve between that part and the axle, if you know what that little sleeve is called, I need to replace that as well. I am going to borrow a hub puller from Autozone and see if the bearings are affected, but I don't think they are. The thing labeled "Not this" is what I keep finding when I try to buy a "rear wheel hub".

**Updated**
Here is a photo of the broken piece, as requested (two angles of the same piece):
[image]

As you can see, that round part of the backing plate is broken and whatever that "sleeve" is is pretty mangled. I'm not sure it can drive this way even if I manage to put the shoes back on it.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the damage? It may not be as bad as it seems.

Comment: The damage of that part is mostly visible - see how it is bent and mangled around the edges?. It is also cracked where the axle sleeve is, I'll update with new photo.

Comment: That sleeve is the axle seal, you'll need to replace that too. I doubt the backing plate is damaged, I've never seen that but anything is possible.

Comment: It is most likely a bad bearing that caused the heat and damage/crack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the backing plate, and that sleeve is part of the axle housing. Also you don't use a hub puller there is a clip in the differential housing that has to be removed.

[image]

Remove the bolt (1) then the pinion shaft (2)

**Note the Manufacture says it's a one time bolt, meaning buy a new one, don't reuse the old one.**

[image]

Push the axle in and the c clip will fall out. Then you will be able to remove the axle.